# GTK gtk_label_set_text segmentation fault

Tags: c, gtk, segmentation-fault

I am learning GTK+ and this simple application crashes every time I run it.

It creates a label in the main window, and every time a button is clicked (the `key_press_event`) the label and the title should swap.

If I comment out the `gtk_label_set_text` in the `change_title` function the title alternates correctly and the app doesn't crash. Why does `gtk_label_set_text` crash my app?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

const gchar first[]="FIRST";
const gchar last[]="LAST";

static void destroy(GtkWidget *window,gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

static gboolean change_title(GtkWidget *widget,GtkLabel *data)
{
  if(strcmp(last,gtk_window_get_title(GTK_WINDOW(widget)))){
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(widget),last);
    gtk_label_set_text(data,first);
  } else {
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(widget),first);
    gtk_label_set_text(data,last);
  }
  return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *window, *label;
  gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),last);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,300,100);
  g_signal_connect(window,"destroy_event",G_CALLBACK(destroy),NULL);

  label = gtk_label_new("caasdasdjadnjadjahadjad");
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),label);

  g_signal_connect(window,"key_press_event",G_CALLBACK(change_title),GTK_LABEL(label));

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: I found the problem using GDB, the label pointer isn't passed correctly to the `change_title` function. I don't know why. (Ex: in `main()` label = `0xb6406608` , in `change_title()` label = `0x807bda8`)

Comment: Have you checked, e.g. in a debugger, that all variables are okay? No `NULL` pointers etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a simple Google search on `key_press_event` I saw that the callback to that event have another argument between the widget and the user-data pointer. The prototype is this:

```
gboolean key_event_handler(GtkWidget *widget,GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data);
```

So simple change your function to this:

```
static gboolean change_title(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, GtkLabel *data)
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, some tutorials sometimes don't include the GdkEvent parameter so I forgot it too. I should have checked the prototype before asking though.

Answer (score 1):

Your `change_title` function has the wrong prototype.

See [the documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event) for the proper prototype. Most `*-event` signals pass the actual event as an argument in the handler function, since the handler typically needs to inspect the event in order to execute. For instance, here the `GdkEventKey` event will contain information about which key was pressed (or released).